# concate 2 dataframes having keys of first not in another

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes..

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
        'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
df_a
```

and

```
    raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
        'first_name': ['Billy', 'Brian', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty'], 
        'last_name': ['Bonder', 'Black', 'Balwner', 'Brice', 'Btisan']} df_b = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
df_b
```

I want output like below..

```
 subject_id first_name last_name
0          1       Alex  Anderson
1          2        Amy  Ackerman
2          3      Allen       Ali
3          4      Alice      Aoni
4          5     Ayoung   Atiches
2          6       Bran   Balwner
3          7      Bryce     Brice
4          8      Betty    Btisan
```

I want concatenate all records of df_a and only those records in df_b which are not in df_a.

I am able to do this by below code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

mask=np.logical_not(df_b['subject_id'].isin(df_a['subject_id']))
    pd.concat([df_a,df_b.loc[mask]])
```

Is there any other short method available directly in function concat and merge.
Please help..

Comment: pd.concat([df_a,df_b]).drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop_duplicates` default keeping the first of the duplicated pair

```
pd.concat([df_a,df_b]).drop_duplicates(['subject_id'])
Out[1015]: 
  subject_id first_name last_name
0          1       Alex  Anderson
1          2        Amy  Ackerman
2          3      Allen       Ali
3          4      Alice      Aoni
4          5     Ayoung   Atiches
2          6       Bran   Balwner
3          7      Bryce     Brice
4          8      Betty    Btisan
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combine_first with set_index()

```
new_df = df_a.set_index('subject_id').combine_first(df_b.set_index('subject_id'))\
.reset_index()

    subject_id  first_name  last_name
0   1           Alex        Anderson
1   2           Amy         Ackerman
2   3           Allen       Ali
3   4           Alice       Aoni
4   5           Ayoung      Atiches
5   6           Bran        Balwner
6   7           Bryce       Brice
7   8           Betty       Btisan
```